# Is it safe to view video files on Google Drive online?

Tags: web-application, malware, google-apps

I have a video file on my Drive which is very old but I am not sure whether it's infected or not. Is it safe to view this MP4 on Google Drive (no downloading only viewing it in the Drive app)?

Comment: We couldn't possibly know what the completely unknown virus might do.

Comment: 1) If in doubt, don't download the file or view it. 2) Use a safe environment such as a virtual machine with up-to-date antivirus installed, and then scan the file. Also, see @schroeder's comment and answer.

Answer (score 1):

The file will be downloaded to your machine's temporary files and viewed with a viewer in your browser (the Drive app). If there is a vulnerability in your browser, there is a chance that your machine will be infected.

If you are using an up-to-date browser, and since the file would have an old virus, if any, you have a low chance of infection.